# Power Automate Add member to Group

Tags: powerapps, power-automate

When I execute the Power Automate,
When the app execute Add Member to Group, 
its show me the error as below.

[image]

and
 the condition
[image]

and

my logic as shown below

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are comparing `Responses` to the string `"Approve"`. The issue might be that `Responses` is the collection of many individual `Response` records. [If you look at this Microsoft Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/modern-approvals), it shows a condition checking if a `Response` is equal to `"Approve"`. Note that `Response` is lacking the trailing `s`.

Assuming you have multiple possible `Response`s to check, and you only need one `"Approve"` response to add them member of the group, [you can use the solution proposed int this power user's forum](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Apply-To-Each-over-Approval-Response/td-p/356290):

> Use filter action to get your information (one with Approve other with
>   Reject)
>
> expression is `item()?['approverResponse']`
>
> [image]
>
> Then use expression `length(dynamicontentfilterarray)` to get your results (will give you count of approve or reject)